# How to install facebook tracking pixel in magento?

Tags: facebook, magento, tracking

I'm trying to install the Facebook tracking pixel on my magento store, from what iv read online it supposed to be added in the following location/file:

app\design\frontend\XXXX\YYYY\template\checkout\success.phtml

However my theme, Ultimo does not have success.phtml in the above location!

The only location this file exists is app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\success.phtml

I have added it in to that file but Facebook can't verify the pixel.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Ultimo theme too, if you don't have success.phtml at your app/design/frontend/ultimo/[YOURTHEME]/template/checkout folder copy it from base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml to your frontend/ultimo/[YOURTHEME]/template/checkout folder and use the code below (I'm using it with my ultimo theme and its verified by Facebook)

```
<?php
//Get Order Number & Order Total
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
$amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
?>

<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '[YOURCUSTOMID]', {'value':'<?php echo $amount; ?>','currency':'TRY'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=[YOURCUSTOMID]&amp;cd[value]=<?php echo $amount; ?>&amp;cd[currency]=TRY&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

Just place this at the top of that success.phtml template and it should do the trick. Don't forget to replace [YOURCUSTOMID] with the ID at the code you got from Facebook. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since November 2015 Facebook asked me to install their new tracking pixel code. Like the last code they forget an alt tag to make sure the code is W3C conform.

I decided to track a PURCHASE and (home)PAGEVIEW.
Within my code you will find more options to track:
Just uncomment and create some PHP IF ike I did with home and success-page

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
fbq('track', 'Search');
fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
fbq('track', 'Lead');
```

Use the code and change your ID (1234567890):

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '1234567890YOURID');
<?php 
// IF WE ARE ON HOMEPAGE
if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) : ?>
fbq('track', "PageView");
<?php endif; ?>
<?php // Facebook Conversion Code for Kaufbestätigungen - Online Trainer Lizenz  
if((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'success')==true)):
$orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()); ?>
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php echo number_format($orderObj->getBaseGrandTotal(),2) ?>', currency: '<?php echo $orderObj->getOrderCurrencyCode()?>'});
<?php endif; ?>
<?php /*?>
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
fbq('track', 'Search');
fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');
fbq('track', 'Lead');
<?php */?>
</script>
<?php 
// IF WE ARE ON HOMEPAGE
if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) : ?>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234567890&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php // Facebook Conversion Code for PURCHASES - PROJECT NAME  
if((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'success')==true)):
$orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()); ?>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234567890&ev=Purchase&noscript=1" /></noscript>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the free facebook pixel magento extensions.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/facebook-pixel-magento-extension/
[image: facebook pixel settings]

[image: Advanced pixel settings]